# PHP doesn't send the reposnse

Tags: php

I have a very weird problem with php and I can't find any explanation for it.
I want to add this line of code to grab extension from the sent file:

```
$extension = array_pop( explode( "." , $_FILES["myFiles"]["name"][$key]);
```

but if i do so php doens't send a respond although the file is saved successfully. If I simply delete this line and hardcode ".jpg" instead $extension it sends the response as expected.

```
<?php

$response = array();

if (isset($_FILES)) {
    foreach ($_FILES["myFiles"]["tmp_name"] as $key => $value) {
        $user = $_POST["user"];
// when i add the line below it deosn't send the response!
        $extension = array_pop( explode( "." , $_FILES["myFiles"]["name"][$key]) );
        move_uploaded_file($value, "uploads/$user.$extension");
    };
    $response["msg"] = "image has been uploaded";
} else {
    $response["msg"] = "selcect an image";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Consider using `pathinfo($_FILES["myFiles"]["name"][$key], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` for a more reliable extension finder.

Comment: You should enable error reporting. I think that line throws the error because `array_pop` accepts an lvalue reference, but you're passing it an rvalue.

Comment: ^^^  This.  The error is displayed and monkeys with the echoed JSON.

Comment: `array_pop(explode(".", "1.2.3"));` this code produces the following error `Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference in php shell code on line 1`

Comment: thank you  @ceejayoz. it works prefectly.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă how to do enable error reporting?

Comment: You'd get a faster response to that question by asking Google how to enable error reporting in PHP. It's a common request, you can find lots of sites with instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_pop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) takes argument by reference. You can't provide argument directly from another function to array_pop.
Instead in your case you should do this:

```
$parts = explode("." , $_FILES["myFiles"]["name"][$key]);
$extension = array_pop($parts);
```

But! You should **NEVER** trust client's data, even if it's just a file extension. It is better to check extension itself (is it jpg, png, svg, gif), also check if the file is really an image, [check size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) of that image, etc...